# Applet Security

Tags: java, applet

I have embedded an applet in an html page which access User's file directory. Its signed. When I write code inside init function then it works very well but when I write this code inside a method and call it with Javascript Then it sends me security exception. Have u any idea how can I solve this problem?

```
public class App extends javax.swing.JApplet {

@Override
public void init() {


 }

public void callMethod(){
    File file = new File("D:/test.txt");
    if(!file.exists()){
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
 }

}


Javascript:  
    window.document.applets[0].callMethod();
```

Comment: I have include code in question.

Comment: @user where's the javascript?

Comment: @Bala R Javascript code included in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the answers to this very similar question can help you: [signed applet gives AccessControlException: access denied, when calling from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068271/signed-applet-gives-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-when-calling-from-java)

Comment: @WhiteFand34 the problem is same as you've provided link but I couldn't understand solution. He is reloading applet at onClick Event which I don't want to do because it takes a  lot of time to load all requried jars etc. What I am trying to achieve is, load applet when page loads and call method when needed. If I will reload all applet again then it stucks browser.

Answer (score 2):

To be trusted, every frame on the stack must be accounted for. Once JavaScript is in the mix, that stops being the case.

To fix it, wrap the trusted code in an `AccessController.doPrivileged()` method. See the JavaDocs for an example.